# Display a contact form (CF7) in all single pages of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a correct way to embed a CF7 module shortcode inside all the single pages of a specific custom post type.
The CPT slug is named 'cpt_proposte', the CF7 shortcode is '[contact-form-7 id="244" title="Richiesta disponibilità"]'.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the single template of `cpt_proposte` Custom post type. Like `single-cpt_proposte.php` file.

At the end of the page before footer, you can add your contact form 7 shortcode. `[contact-form-7 id="244" title="Richiesta disponibilità"]`